# IntelliJ IDEA: Define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, environment-variables

**IDE:** IntelliJ IDEA
**OS:** Windows 7
When use `Run` option in IntelliJ with configured `Django server`:
[image]

Then this command is executed:

> runnerw.exe D:\Kursy\VirtualEnv\env1\Scripts\python.exe
>   D:/Kursy/Django/manage.py runserver 8000

And I getting error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the
>   environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I can run Django app with Windows **CMD**
First by starting my Virtual python environment:

```
D:\Kursy\VirtualEnv\env1\Scripts>activate.bat
```

Then by navigating to Django app directory:

```
(env1) D:\Kursy\VirtualEnv\env1\Scripts>cd D:\Kursy\Django
(env1) D:\Kursy\Django>python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
May 11, 2014 - 16:25:06
Django version 1.6.4, using settings 'first_django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Everything works fine.
I don't want to set global enviroment variable in Windows so I understand that it should be set in `Run Configuratuion` for `Run` option in IntelliJ - am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right, but you're missing that DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE must have a value (which is the settings module file. the line should look like this:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_proj.settings;.....
```

Comment: It'is strange that value should be in import style. I've tried to add path to file (like `first_django\settings.py`) and result: `ImportError: Could not import settings 'first_django\settings.py' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): Import by filename is not supported.` In `Modules` settings: path can be added and it works

Answer (score 2):

@radev answer works for settings for specific `Run Configuration`.
There is alternative way to avoid `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` error in IntelliJ `Run`
Going to `File`>`ProjectStructure...` (or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) and adding reference to project `settings.py` here:
[image]

sets value for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable for project in IntelliJ so `Run` works with default settings.

Comment: I don't see "Django" facet in Intellij IDEA. you probably meant PyCharm IDE, which is different.

Comment: As far as I remember, you need python plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=631 (and probably IntelliJ Professional edition)

Comment: I have both, but don't see Django setup in IDEA 14. maybe it was removed and only exists in PyCharm now?